# 2D jagged trail

Tags: unity-game-engine

At the moment i'm trying to develop a 2D game. As you can see from the picture my trail is jagged even though my min vertex distance is set to 0.1.
My player is moved via `Update()` method.

Any suggestions to make it look like the bottom picture?

[image: As you can see it's jagged]

[image]

EDIT:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That jag you're seeing *is* 0.1 distance.

Look at your *width* value: 0.3.  Can you honestly tell me that that jag you're seeing is *more* than 1/3rd the total line width?  Those values are measured in *scene units*, not pixels.

Odds are your pixel scale is 100 pixels per unit (which at 0.1 vertex distance would be...... ten pixels or about the size of your jags)

To fix it you need to either:

a) use a different pixel scale and refactor your entire code base to handle the new values

b) change the minimum vertex distance to 0.01 or smaller.

Comment: How do i change my pixel scale? Because i don't have a canvas

Comment: Then it would be on the camera, the orthographic size: this is how many *scene units* wide the camera can see, which means that so many pixels are so many scene units.  The default camera size 5, which is both +5 and -5 for a total width of 10 scene units. Covering a typical screen resolution of say...1000 pixels wide...is 100 pixels per scene unit. But that is the least efficient solution. If everything else "looks and works fine" use option B. @DavideNale

Comment: Option B doesn't work, but i found an alternative solution: removing the rigidbody and applying hardcoded movement.

Comment: What happens when you try to adjust the minimum distance? Been a few years since I poked at the trail renderer.

Comment: well... after option A and B il looks like in EDIT. (my ortho distance is now at 25)

Comment: Ah, at that scale I can see that there is some weirdness going on in the movement: you can see the line renderer *turning* to face the jag direction (there are multiple verticies in each jag corner) which points to a problem in the movement code (however it's being handled; in your case the rigidbody, which is doing something weird and probably not fixable from outside) rather than the *trail renderer* itself being broken or incorrectly configured.  So yes, in that case, the only solution is to move to your own movement system.

Comment: Ok, by the way i'm just using an `rb.AddForce`